# iphone connect on ubuntu unhandled error (255)

Tags: ios, iphone

I was able to access the files from my iphone some time ago, but I guess that after an update it doesn't work anymore I get unhandled exception (255) or 20.

Libimobiledevice-utils is installed:

```
libimobiledevice-utils is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libclamav6 libjs-node-uuid libllvm3.6
  libllvm3.6:i386 libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 libx264-142
```

I runned the command below but got an error:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair

ERROR: Device aaba2bc33b23a0cd8cb4eaa9f52c8004dbcfac16 is not paired with this host
```

I also executed the commands above, but still not working:

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is an attempt by Apple to stop the use of fake charging cables. You can solve the trust-loop error with IOS7 mobile devices by installing the latest release of libimobiledevice

Reference : https://askubuntu.com/a/433872

Comment: libimobiledevice-utils is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gyp libc-ares-dev libc-ares2 libclamav6 libjs-node-uuid libllvm3.6
  libllvm3.6:i386 libv8-3.14-dev libv8-3.14.5 libx264-142

Comment: libimobiledevice is already installed and i called the unpair/pair command, but still not working.

Comment: did sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown but still not working, while screen is unlocked